# Angular2 don't compile on specific folder

Tags: angular, webpack

My angular2 app compiles automatically if some files within the src-directory changes. I start it simply with `ng serve`

The problem is I'm uploading and storing files in the assets folder, the app always recompiles.

Can I prevent this behaviour for a specific folder and allow changes to it?

Comment: I figured it out myself. It is ok, that the app recompiles, but the refreshing was the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple: `ng serve --live-reload false` does recompile, but not refresh my page which was just what I needed.